# Convergence in random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The problem is this:

> A fair die is tossed $20$ times. Use the Chebyshev Inequality to bound the probability that the total number of dots is between $60$ and $80$.

How do I go about solving this? The farthest I've gotten is to say that average number of dots lies between 3 and 4, and the $E[X]$ of number of total dots should lie between this number for 1 roll.

Comment: That's a very interesting problem.  What is your question?

Comment: Dear Raaj: couple of general tips. Text is cheap, so don't use abbreviations like "no." for number. Also, it looks like you are using the notation $E[X]$ as an abbreviation for the phrase "the expected value," which is also a bad idea. $E[X]$ is some real number, so you are literally saying something like "and the 8.3253 of number of total dots...". It would be better to say "and the expected value of number..." or "and $E[X]$ should lie between..." Clear writing goes a long way for helping your understanding and your readers' understanding.

Comment: Also, I guess "lie between this number" is probably something more like "lies between these numbers"... is that so?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_i$ be the number of dots of the $i$-th throw, $1\le i\le n=20$.

Then $\operatorname{E}[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i]=\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{E}[X_i]=n\cdot\sum_{j=1}^{6}\frac{j}{6}=3.5n=70$.

So you have the mean $\mu$, which lies **perfectly in the middle** of the given range $[60,80]$.

Calculate the standard deviation $\sigma$, and apply the formula for some multiplier that fits the situation.